# is their a way to set pod restart policy to be every 10 seconds when the container status ERROR or CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Hello I am trying to change the restart policy from the default policy to be restart every 10 seconds. without using init containers

I get that only init containers can change their restart policy
.restartPolicy: Forbidden: may not be set for non-init containers